# How to prevent Angular child component ngAfterViewChecked on parent mousemove event?

Tags: angular, components, lifecycle

I noticed that `ngAfterViewChecked` of child components are always triggered when I catch the `mousemove` event from the parent component even if the event does not change data. How to prevent that from happening so I can use the `ngAfterViewChecked` life-cycle to check the child's DOM.

EDIT:
Here's the code snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-egrlgr.
`AppComponent` is the parent with `HostListener` for `mousemove` event. `ChildComponent` is where I want to catch the `ngAfterViewChecked` life-cycle.

I tried to add `event.preventDefault();` and `event.stopPropagation();` but it didn't work.

Comment: Please add sample code scenario , nothing is going to make sense by this theory based question. use stackblitz.com to create sample and then ask question based on that.

Comment: Thanks @SeanCh here's the code snippet: https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-ivy-egrlgr

Comment: what is your ultimate goal in layman terms excluding the events verbiage ?

Comment: I am catching the mousemove event for dragging div purpose. While I need to check DOM updates on the child component on its ngAfterViewChecked. The issue is ngAfterViewChecked is always triggered even if the mousemove event from the parent did not change the DOM.

Comment: so at functional level the goal is to make child div draggable. why i am asking this is you might be over-engineering and there might be a simple solution.

Comment: regardless of what feature I am trying to achieve, it doesn't make sense to trigger ngAfterViewChecked in child components on parent DOM events specially if there are no data changes and DOM changes